# How run specific function from activity which is reordering to front

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-asynctask, android-activity

I am a beginner in programming and also in Android development.

I have 2 `Activities` with the flag `ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT` and I need to retain both `Activities`, so I cannot use `startActivityForResult(...)` because cannot use `finish()`.

I use an `AsyncTask` to retrieve data from a server in both `Activities`. This data updates content in my `Activity`.

How could I start this `AsyncTask` immediately after reordering the `Activity` to front?

Comment: Not sure I understand your question. When the activity comes to the front, `onNewIntent()` is called, can't you start your `AsyncTask` there?

Comment: You dont need to understand my question to answer me correctly. You are genius and im noob, thanks a lot.

Comment: OK, I created an answer so that this question doesn't go unanswered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the activity comes to the front, `onNewIntent() is called`, you can start your `AsyncTask` there.

Comment: David, is there any way to send data from our first activity to my second activity? I need to run my specific function only after first successful login, not after every closing user profile window

Comment: You can send data by adding "extras" to the `Intent` when you start one `Activity` from another. If that isn't appropriate, you can use static member variables (globals) to pass information between activities.